# $2\sin^2\theta - 2\sin\theta = \cos^2 \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the values of $\theta$, to 3 significant figures, in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ for which

> $2\sin^2\theta - 2\sin\theta = \cos^2 \theta$

This question is solid and i cannot seem to do it

Answer (score 3):

$$2\sin^2t-2\sin t=\cos^2t(=1-\sin^2t)\iff3\sin^2t-2\sin t-1=0$$

Now look at the quadratic

$$3x^2-2x-1=0\implies x_{1,2}=\frac{2\pm 4}{6}\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

First write $\cos^2 \theta = 1 - \sin^2\theta$.

$$2\sin^2 θ - 2\sin θ = 1 -\sin^2 \theta \iff 3\sin^2 \theta - 2\sin \theta - 1 = 0$$

Then note you'll have a quadratic equation in $\sin \theta.$  To see this more clearly, let $x = \sin \theta$, and solve the quadratic equation.

$$\begin{align} 3x^2 - 2x - 1 & = 0 \iff (3x + 1)(x-1) = 0 \\ \\ & \implies x = 1, \text{ or } x = -\frac 13\end{align}$$

Now, remember that $x = \sin \theta$. So we have that $\sin \theta = 1$ or $\sin \theta = -\frac 13$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Would you please mind adding a backward slash before the $sin$ in  third line of your solution please?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you...

Comment: @DonAntonio I would not bother amWhy, but I could not edit two characters so I said him, it was looking a little odd on such a well formatted answer. I beg your and his pardon for bothering him.

Comment: @Hawk Don't worry about it. Thank you for noticing. It's "all good" now.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I didn't mean to bother you. Thank you for realising.

Answer (score 0):

We have,
$2\sin^2 \theta-2\sin \theta=\cos^2 \theta$
$2\sin^2 \theta-2\sin \theta=1-\sin^2 \theta$
$3\sin^2 \theta-2\sin \theta-1=0$
By middle-term factorisation,
$(3\sin \theta+1)(\sin \theta-1)=0$
$\sin \theta=-\dfrac13,1$
I hope you can now find out the value of $\arcsin(-\dfrac13)$.